# Using the "Select" tag, how I can add "selected" option using DataSet and SqlDataAdapter in C #?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, selected, sqldataadapter

I am using the `Select` tag but this is building in the `CodeBehing`. I have a `user` and this work in an `Area` and I have his `idArea`, So I used the follow query to get all Area an set it in the Select tag

```
string area_consulta = @"SELECT idArea, Nombre_area FROM Area";
```

then

```
SqlCommand comand3 = new SqlCommand(area_consulta, con);
DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
var adapter3 = new SqlDataAdapter(comand3);
adapter3.Fill(ds3, "Area");
SelectArea.DataSource = ds3;
SelectArea.DataTextField = "Nombre_area";
SelectArea.DataValueField = "idArea";
SelectArea.DataBind();
```

but this only set the data but need to add the "selected" option to the area where the user works

how can I do?

**.ASPX**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Area</label>
 <select id="SelectArea" name="D1" runat="server" class ="form-control"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using  an HTML select with `runat="server` rather than an `<asp:DropDownList>`. The latter has `SelectedIndex` you can use to set which item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectArea` is an instace of [HtmlSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and it has two ways of setting the selected item.

First, use `SelectedIndex` is you know what index is the value you want to have selected:

```
SelectArea.SelectedIndex = 5; // or whatever
```

Second, use `Value` if you know what value should be selected, but do not know the index:

```
SelectArea.Value = "selected_area_id";
```

Comment: SelectedIndex returns an object or ID of that option?? I ask that because the I used this ``<option id="(idArea)">(Name Area)</option>``

Comment: @zhelon, `SelectedIndex` returns index, that is 0-based position of the selected option in the list of all options. `Value` should return whatever is in the `value` attribute of the selected option. `id` is not used in this mechanism at all to the best of my knowledge, not sure why you are relying on it